# ubuntu german keyboard with alt-q, alt-y, alt-p for umlauts

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-layout, german

I'm somewhat irrationally used to a keyboard layout which I think on my previous installation (debian) was called "German (international)", but I'm not sure.  The point is that it was the standard US English QWERTY layout with umlauts under alt-q, alt-y, alt-p.

As an alternative I found "German (US)" in my current ubuntu installation, which I guess is more logical (umlauts are under alt-a, alt-u, alt-o), but the muscle memory is just killing me. Does anybody know how could I turn on this previous german layout in the default ubuntu 23.10 installation?

Comment: There are various apps to remap key combinations, https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=linux . See if one gives your ä, ö, and ü with the right touch.